# Modify a jQuery function to resize a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I currently use a jQuery function to create a square div. The square size is based on the height of the browser variable. It works very well.

```
<script>
$(window).ready(updateWidth);
$(window).resize(updateWidth);

function updateWidth()
{
var square = $('.square');
var size = square.height();

square.css('width',size);
}
</script>


.square {
height:100%;
float:left;
position:relative;
}
```

What I want to do is : for certains div using this function (.half), divide the width by two.

For a ".square" div : keep the  width, keep the  height;

For a ".square .half" div : keep the  height, new width = width / 2;

I dont know how to modify my function, if someone can help me.

Thanks,

Sebastien

Comment: Wait. On each "resizing" for the window you want to do this? This is too much and illogical, can you think about it again? What do you exactly expect to have at last?

Comment: @Ashraf Samhouri Its to keep my square width a 100% height of the container,even if the user resizes the browser, this is not a good solution?

Comment: +Sebastian I think I wasn't getting your point. No, if that makes sense for you it's alright!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
function updateWidth()
{
    var square = $('.square');
    var squareHalf = $('.half');
    var size = square.height();
    square.css('width',size);
    squareHalf.css({'width':''+size/2+'px','height':''+size/2+'px'});
}
```

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5MYBX/4/)

Answer (score 0):

> Hi There, Try this. you need to set the resize event on documnet ready.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
   $(window).resize(function(){
     put your code here
});
});
});
```

> Thanks,